# Problems creating datetime series graph in R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, timeserieschart

I am trying to create a graph with the following characteristics:

- x-axis: time and date
- y-axis: data

here you can download my dataframe: https://my.cloudme.com/josechka/data

I try to produce the graph using:

```
p <- ggplot(data,aes(x = Date, y = Var,group = 1)) 
        + geom_line() 
        + scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m/%d/%Y")) 
        + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 70000))    
p
```

And I get the result:

```
Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only
```

I am quite new in R and ggplot. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `as.Date()` on your date column first

Comment: ... as keegan says but with `format="%m/%d/%Y"`

Answer (score 2):

As suggested you have to format the Date column into a `Date` object.

```
data$Date<-as.Date(data$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

Now you can use your script in order to create the plot:

```
library("ggplo2") 
library("scales")
p <- ggplot(data,aes(x = Date, y = Var,group = 1)) 
        + geom_line() 
        + scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m/%d/%Y")) 
        + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 70000))    
p
```

And this is the resulting plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. They helped me to find out the solution. Both comments allow to represent my data. However, there is small problem: data from the same day is grouped and it is not possible to see the daily behaviour of the variable. I tested to format the Date column using the next command:

```
as.POSIXct(data$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

It worked out. However it is important to have the original data in the format d/m/Y h:m:s. Thanks very much for the comments which help me a lot to solve my problem.