# "Unambiguous date format" using ggplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a csv file with a column of dates and times in the format m/dd/yy H:M. I would like to plot this along my x-axis, with data along the y-axis. I have seen this post: [Problems creating datetime series graph in R using ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977838/problems-creating-datetime-series-graph-in-r-using-ggplot), but at least some of the suggestions seem to be outdated.

I try to produce the graph by this:

```
discharge <- read.csv("~/mac2017/Everything_plot/discharge2.csv", header 
= TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE)

discharge$Date_Time <- as.POSIXct(discharge$Date_Time, "%m/%d/%y %h:%m")

ggplot(data=discharge, aes(x=Date_Time, y=Discharge, type=1, group=1))+
    geom_line()+
    scale_x_date(date_labels = ("%b-%Y")) + #breaks = date_breaks("1 
month"), labels = date_format("%m/%Y"))+
    scale_y_continuous()
```

I have tried formatting the Date column into a `Date` object as the answers on that post suggested, but continued to get this error:

```
Error in as.Date(x, tx, ...) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Thus, I switched to using the as.POSIXct command, but have been getting the same error about an unambiguous format. I have tried using `strptime` but have again been receiving the same error. I thought that `strptime` would have fixed the unambiguous format error, as it is used to specify the current format.

Here are the first few lines of my very long csv:

```
Date        Time    Date_Time       Discharge
8/23/2016   0:00    8/23/16 0:00    92.00
8/23/2016   0:15    8/23/16 0:15    91.00
8/23/2016   0:30    8/23/16 0:30    90.00
8/23/2016   0:45    8/23/16 0:45    89.00
8/23/2016   1:00    8/23/16 1:00    88.00
8/23/2016   1:15    8/23/16 1:15    87.00
8/23/2016   1:30    8/23/16 1:30    86.00
8/23/2016   1:45    8/23/16 1:45    86.00
8/23/2016   2:00    8/23/16 2:00    86.00
8/23/2016   2:15    8/23/16 2:15    85.00
8/23/2016   2:30    8/23/16 2:30    84.00
8/23/2016   2:45    8/23/16 2:45    83.00
8/23/2016   3:00    8/23/16 3:00    82.00
```

I am fairly new to R. Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can't use (systems can't use) `"%m"` for both minutes and months. Have a look at `?strptime` and you can see that you need `"%M"` for minutes and `"%H"` for hours - `h` is equivalent to `b` which is abbreviated month name.

Answer (score 0):

consider using the package "lubridate".  It is slightly more intuitive to use than R's built-in date/time functions.  For instance, I could use mdy() function to set/extract your date column.  Or use the month() function to set/extract the month.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `tidyverse` for tools that will help you with data import, cleaning, and working with dates and time.  The `readr::read_csv` function and the `lubridate` package are going to be very helpful.

For example, we'll first load the namespaces and save a temp .csv

```
library(readr)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# save data as a csv for the example
cat(
"Date,       Time,   Date_Time,      Discharge
8/23/2016,  0:00,   8/23/16 0:00,   92.00
8/23/2016,  0:15,   8/23/16 0:15,   91.00
8/23/2016,  0:30,   8/23/16 0:30,   90.00
8/23/2016,  0:45,   8/23/16 0:45,   89.00
8/23/2016,  1:00,   8/23/16 1:00,   88.00
8/23/2016,  1:15,   8/23/16 1:15,   87.00
8/23/2016,  1:30,   8/23/16 1:30,   86.00
8/23/2016,  1:45,   8/23/16 1:45,   86.00
8/23/2016,  2:00,   8/23/16 2:00,   86.00
8/23/2016,  2:15,   8/23/16 2:15,   85.00
8/23/2016,  2:30,   8/23/16 2:30,   84.00
8/23/2016,  2:45,   8/23/16 2:45,   83.00
8/23/2016,  3:00,   8/23/16 3:00,   82.00",
file = "discharge2.csv")
```

Reading the data in via `readr` is as follows:

```
# read in the data via readr::read_csv, reading in all data/time columns as
# characters and the Discharge column as a number
discharge <- readr::read_csv("discharge2.csv", col_type = "cccd")
```

We will set the correct date-time storage mode for each of the date time variables.  This is done using the `dplry::mutate` call and the `lubridate` functions `mdy`, `hm`, `mdy_hm`.  These functions will parse the date-time format and store the result accordingly.

```
# set the date/time storage modes
discharge <-
  discharge %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Date = lubridate::mdy(Date),
                Time = lubridate::hm(Time),
                Date_Time = lubridate::mdy_hm(Date_Time))
```

A simple graphic

```
ggplot(discharge) +
  aes(x = Date_Time, y = Discharge) +
  geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image]